# CheckboxList, MVC, Many-To-Many Relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model, view, viewmodel

I have a `Request` class and a `Building` class with a many to many relationship. A Request can be associated with 1 or more Buildings. I want to take advantage of EditorTemplates to generate checkboxes for each building and check them if associated with the Request.

This might seem like a bit of a loaded question but I'm familiar with EditorTempaltes, ViewModels, etc. I'm just not quite sure how to wire the two up with a many-to-many relationship and checkboxes.

1. Do I need to add a bool property to my Building class to indicated checked status?
2. For the EditorTemplate how do I indicated status of checked with the many-to-many relationship?
3. Should I add an `IEnumerable<Building>` to my Request viewmodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Many to many checkbox and mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311823/many-to-many-checkbox-and-mvc)